# TypeError: Cannot read property 'showMessageBox' of undefined electron in node js

Tags: node.js, express, electron

Below code is just to display the dialog box using electron node module.

**app.js**

```
    const { dialog } = require('electron')
    const response = dialog.showMessageBox(null);
    console.log(response);
```

Need help to understand why I am getting below error message:

```
    const response = dialog.showMessageBox(null);
                            ^
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'showMessageBox' of undefined
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\1217688\Desktop\WebApp\node-elect-test\app.js:2:25)
        at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:190:16)
        at bootstrap_node.js:662:3
```

Comment: post your main.js file?

Comment: app.js - this is my main file

Comment: do you have electron in your package.json, and did you run `npm install`?

Comment: Yes, i did install electron npm module

Answer (score 3):

In renderer process, add .remote

```
const { dialog } = require('electron').remote
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the dialog module when the app is ready:

```
app.on('ready', () => {
  const { dialog } = require('electron')
  dialog.showMessageBox(null);
})
```